# How to toggle class name of an element using its parent?

Tags: javascript, dom

The last line `helement.childNodes` gives me the child elements, but I am unable to get the class List of child elements or toggle them. Please help.

```js
function toggleclassbox2(elm) {
  var helement = document.querySelector("#firstselectionbox");
  console.log(helement.childNodes);
}
```

```html
<div class="box-5" id="firstselectionbox">
  <button class="firstselection highlighted" id="constructionbutton" onclick="toggleclassbox2(this)" value=1>Construction</button>
  <button class="firstselection" id="interiorbutton" onclick="toggleclassbox2(this)" value=2>Interiors</button>
</div>
```

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll("#firstselectionbox > *")`

Comment: Are you looking to get the attribute value of the `class` attribute of each of the `<button>` elements (`firstselection highlighted`, for example)?

Comment: Yes, and I want to toggle the highlighted class

Answer (score 0):

To get to the attribute values of the `class` attribute of each of the `<button>` child elements of the `<div>` element, try:

```
var helement = document.querySelectorAll("#firstselectionbox button");
for (let he of helement)
{
target = he.getAttribute("class");
console.log(target)
}
```

Output:

```
"firstselection highlighted"
"firstselection"
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// to ensure that the JavaScript is run only once the DOM has been
// created, so the elements to which we're binding JavaScript to
// exist:
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (e) => {

  // defining the function using Arrow function syntax,
  // the evt (the Event Object) is passed to the
  // function automatically by the later use of
  // EventTarget.addEventListener():
  const toggleclassbox2 = (evt) => {
  
      // the currentTarget property of the Event Object contains
      // a reference to the element to which the EventListener()
      // was bound (evt.target could also work, but a <button>
      // element can contain other descendant HTML elements, and
      // would refer to the child element that was triggered):
      const clickedButton = evt.currentTarget,
        // a reference to the parentNode of the current element:
        parent = clickedButton.parentNode,
        // using spread syntax with an Array literal to convert
        // the iterable HTMLCollection into an Array of child
        // elements (Element.children() returns only HTMLElements,
        // not text-nodes or comment-nodes that might need to
        // be filtered out from a Node.childNodes collection):
        allButtons = [...parent.children],
        
        // here we use Array.prototype.map(), along with an
        // anonymous Arrow function, to iterate over the
        // Array and from that iteration create a new Array:
        buttonsAndClasses = allButtons.map(
          // btn is a reference to the current Element of the
          // Array of Elements over which we're iterating:
          (btn) => {
            // here we're returning an Object (because I'm not
            // quite sure of what you're trying to do), which
            // contains:
            return {
              // a property of 'id', which contains the id of
              // the current <button> element:
              id: btn.id,
              // a reference to the current <button> element-node:
              node: btn,
              // an Array of class-names, using Array.from() to
              // convert that iterable DOMTokenList into an Array:
              classes: Array.from(btn.classList),
            }
          }),
          
        // here we get a list of unique classes (again, I'm not entirely
        // certain what you're looking to receive from the function so
        // this may or may not be necessary); here we use new Set()
        // to obtain only the unique entries returned from the function
        // calls within:
        uniqueClasses = new Set(
          // here we again use Array.prototype.map(), along with an Arrow
          // function, to iterate over the Array of <button> elements:
          allButtons.map(
            // a reference to the current <button> element of the Array,
            // and again we convert the DOMTokenList into an Array using
            // Array.from()
            (btn) => Array.from(btn.classList)
          // finally we use Array.prototype.flat() to flatten the
          // multidimensional Array - an Array of Arrays - into a single
          // dimensional Array:
          ).flat()
        );

      // Element.matches() returns a Boolean true if the element
      // matches the supplied CSS selector, or a Boolean false
      // if the element does not match:
      if (clickedButton.matches('.highlighted')) {
        // here we remove the 'highlighted' class-name, using the
        // Element.classList API:
        clickedButton.classList.remove('highlighted');
      } else {
        // otherwise we remove the 'highlighted' class-name from any
        // element that might have it, using NodeList.prototype.forEach():
        parent.querySelectorAll('.highlighted').forEach(
          // highlighted is a reference to the current element of 
          // the Array of elements over which we're iterating;
          // we again use the Element.classList API to remove
          // the 'highlighted' class-name:
          (highlighted) => highlighted.classList.remove('highlighted')
        );
        // here we use the Element.classList API to add the 'highlighted'
        // class-name to the <button>:
        clickedButton.classList.add('highlighted');
      }

    },
    
    // here we get a NodeList of all the <button> elements that are
    // children of any element with the class of 'box-5':
    buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.box-5 > button');
  // here we use NodeList.prototype.forEach() to iterate over the
  // NodeList of <button> elements:
  buttons.forEach(
    // button is a reference to the current <button> element of the
    // NodeList of <button> element-nodes over which we're iterating;
    // we use EventTarget.addEventListener() to bind the named function
    // - toggleclassbox2() - as the event-handler for the 'click' event
    // (note the deliberate lack of parentheses):
    (button) => button.addEventListener('click', toggleclassbox2)
  );
});
```

```css
:root {
  --button-gradient-start: silver;
  --button-gradient-end: white;
}

*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

button {
  background: #fff linear-gradient(0deg, var(--button-gradient-start), var(--button-gradient-end) 60%, var(--button-gradient-end));
  border: 1px solid darkgrey;
  border-radius: 0.3em;
  padding: 0.2em 0.5em;
}

button:hover {
  --button-gradient-start: silver;
}

button.highlighted {
  --button-gradient-start: lime;
}

button:is(:active) {
  --button-gradient-start: salmon;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-5" id="firstselectionbox">
  <!-- Note that I removed the inline event-handlers from your HTML
       in order for easier maintenance going forward and to use
       unobtrusive JavaScript -->
  <button class="firstselection highlighted" id="constructionbutton" value=1>Construction</button>
  <button class="firstselection" id="interiorbutton" value=2>Interiors</button>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/dobknLzc/).

References:

- [`Array.prototype.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat).
- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`Array.prototype.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).
- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- [`Element.classList` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).
- [`Element.matches()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches).
- [`Node.childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/node/childNodes).
- [`Node.parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode).
- [`parentNode.children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children).